# Php возврат данных рекурсивной функции

Tags: php

Собсно простой код. Почему в итоге я получаю пустоту - не понимаю. Из текста убирается всё кроме цифр и точек. В итоге text становится 24.5.. Далее применяется функция которая проверяет последний символ и если это точка - убирает его. Далее вызывает себя. Если это не точка - возвращает данные. По факту вывод - пустота. В чём мой косяк?

```
$text = "24.5 кв.м.";
$text = preg_replace('~[^.0-9]+~', "", $text);
function removeDotintheend($text)
{
    $last_symbol = substr($text, strlen($text)-1, 1);
    if ($last_symbol == "."){
        $text = substr($text, 0, strlen($text)-1);
        removeDotintheend($text);
    }
    else
    {
        return $text;
    }
}
$text = removeDotintheend($text);
echo $text;
```

Comment: не проще убрать regex'ом? `/\.+$/`

Comment: Вы забыли перед рекурсивным вызовом функции поставить `return`, в итоге этот вызов ни куда не возвращает свой результат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "24.5 кв.м.";
$text = preg_replace('~[^.0-9]+~', "", $text);
function removeDotintheend($text){
    $last_symbol = substr($text, strlen($text)-1, 1);
    if($last_symbol == "."){
        $text = substr($text, 0, strlen($text)-1);
        $text = removeDotintheend($text);
}

    return $text;

}
$text = removeDotintheend($text);
echo $text;
```

Ошибка была в removeDotintheend($text); вы выполняли функцию, но ее результат не принимали.
И нужно было убрать else{}

Проверка http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2516794d5c7257c91437e3be9517a16066fbf283

Answer (score 1):

Функцию `removeDotintheend` следует убрать, заменив библиотечной `rtrim`.

```
$text = "24.5 кв.м.";
$text = rtrim(preg_replace('~[^.0-9]+~', "", $text), '.');
echo $text;
```

Ценой чуть более сложной регулярки можно убрать и эту функцию.

```
$text = "24.5..... кв.м.";
$text = preg_replace('/(\d+)(\.?\d+)?.*/', '\1\2', $text);
var_dump($text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по входным данным и результату, который вы хотите получить, вам проще использовать функцию:

```
$text = "24.5 кв.м.";
$text = explode(" ", $text)[0];
```

и в результате получим 24.5

Comment: Да уже нашёл более простой вариант в виде rtrim просто было интересно чяднт. $text = rtrim($text, '.');